# using action helpers in Zend Framework 1.8

Tags: zend-framework, action, helper

Hi am starting off with Zend Framework and have a question about action helpers.  My first application is a simple authentication system (following a tutorial from a book).  The registration and authentication seems to work fine but the redirect doesn't.

I have a customer controller that has this among others:

```
class CustomerController extends Zend_Controller_Action 
{

// some code here......

public function authenticateAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if (!$request->isPost()) {
        return $this->_helper->redirector('login');
    }

    // Validate
    $form = $this->_forms['login'];
    if (!$form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
        return $this->render('login');
    }

    if (false === $this->_authService->authenticate($form->getValues())) {
        $form->setDescription('Login failed, please try again.');
        return $this->render('login');
    }

    return $this->_helper->redirector('index');
}
```

the authenticate url is http://localhost/customer/authenticate and this seems to work fine but it does not redirect.  After authentication I get a blank page which looks like its taking me to the index and just sits there.  I tried using '/index' instead but that did not help either.  Do I need to do anything special to make the redirector helper work?  I have a logout action which behaves the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out there may be a problem with my setup.  The code above is perfect, works on another computer.

Answer (score 0):

You should call

```
 $this->_helper->redirector('index');
```

**without** the **return**.

Comment: Have you tried putting the redirector at the top of your method just to check if it works?

Do you have error reporting turned on?